# Stop event propagation in JavaScript overlay menu to Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created some editBox and buttons in a Google overlayView on top of Google map in JavaScript. Whenever I am clicking on any button, editBox or anywhere on overlayView, Google map is also accepting those mouse events. How can I restrict mouse events so they can't propagate through overlayView?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(gotoBtn, 'click', function(e) {
    ///DO SOMETHING
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

For buttons, I am using the following method, but I don't want to put the same everywhere for all. Is there any other logical way?

Comment: Can you support your question with jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added div in overlayView and stopping mouse propagation there.

```
var panes = this.getPanes();
panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);

/// Code for stoping event propagation to m_map
div.onclick = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, 'mousedown', function (event) {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
        if(event.stopPropogation)
            event.stopPropagation();
});
```